# How to incorporate cross validation into training process in spektral?

Tags: python, keras, cross-validation

I am testing a sample graph neural network using spektral as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tensorflow.keras.losses import CategoricalCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_accuracy
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

from spektral.data import DisjointLoader
from spektral.datasets import TUDataset
from spektral.models import GeneralGNN

np.random.seed(0)

batch_size = 16
learning_rate = 0.0001
epochs = 100

data = TUDataset("PROTEINS")
np.random.shuffle(data)
split = int(0.8 * len(data))
data_tr, data_te = data[:split], data[split:]

loader_tr = DisjointLoader(data_tr, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
loader_te = DisjointLoader(data_te, batch_size=batch_size)


model = GeneralGNN(data.n_labels, activation="softmax")
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate)
loss_fn = CategoricalCrossentropy()
model.compile(loss=loss_fn,
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=categorical_accuracy)

history = model.fit(loader_tr.load(),
                    steps_per_epoch=loader_tr.steps_per_epoch,
                    epochs=epochs)

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['categorical_accuracy'])
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(["Loss", "Categorical Accuracy"])
plt.show()
```

How can one incorporate cross validation into the training process above?

If I just do

```
history = model.fit(loader_tr.load(),
                    steps_per_epoch=loader_tr.steps_per_epoch,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data=loader_te.load())
```

the training halts right after the first epoch. I guess it happens because `steps_per_epoch` is not set for the loader of the validation data. But I have no clue how to do that.

Does anyone have any experience in such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `steps_per_epoch`, the keyword for validation data is `validation_steps`:

```py
history = model.fit(loader_tr.load(),
                    steps_per_epoch=loader_tr.steps_per_epoch,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    validation_data=loader_te.load(),
                    validation_steps=loader_te.steps_per_epoch)
```

This will work as intended. Otherwise, the validation loop will run until the loader is exhausted (which, by default is never).

Cheers